# Junit libraries not recognized

Tags: java, maven, junit

For some reason my Junit classes don't work anymore and don't recognize the imports. It's a Maven project and as seen in the image I have added Junit as a dependency.

[Unknown libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS7Ao.png)

pom.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>CarPartShop</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                    <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The Junit classes reside in a package caled uniTesting as seen in the image (as well the folder structure):

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvLDI.png)

P.S. I am using Intellij as an IDE.

Comment: I recommend to use the bom file of the junit jupiter project instead... (take a deeper look into this: https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/tree/main/episode-2 also https://youtu.be/IVwbrhYCLpc). Furthermore I would question what is the idea of the `JavaDoc` directory?

Answer (score 0):

The fix seems for me it was to create a new test file inside the package, and then when I hovered over the library it said add to class path and voila, everything is back to normal